# How do I use PropBank for prepositional phrases in my semantic role analyzer code?

Tags: java, nlp

I am trying to improve the accuracy of my semantic role analyser by introducing labeling for prepositional phrases. So far the code does this for verb phrases. How do I integrate prop bank into my code for this? I looked around a bit but couldn't find much help on the web.

My code outputs the symantic as well as the syntactic tree. E.g. for the clause -

> Later he became one of the central spirits of the Army Language
>   Program and the language school of Washington Foreign Service
>   Institute

The following is the output:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (ADVP (RB Later))
    (, ,)
    (NP (PRP he))
    (VP (VBD became)
      (NP
        (NP (CD one))
        (PP (IN of)
          (NP
            (NP (DT the) (JJ central) (NNS spirits))
            (PP (IN of)
              (NP
                (NP (DT the) (NNP Army) (NNP Language) (NNP Program))
                (CC and)
                (NP
                  (NP (DT the) (NN language) (NN school))
                  (PP (IN of)
                    (NP
                      (NP (NNP Washington) (POS 's))
                      (NNP Foreign) (NNP Service) (NNP Institute))))))))))
    (. .)))  



DEP Tree0:became[3-VBD]
     (advmod) 1:Later[0-RB]
     (nsubj) 1:he[2-PRP]
     (xcomp) 1:one[4-CD]
          (prep_of) 2:spirits[8-NNS]
               (det) 3:the[6-DT]
               (amod) 3:central[7-JJ]
               (prep_of) 3:Program[13-NNP]
                    (det) 4:the[10-DT]
                    (nn) 4:Army[11-NNP]
                    (nn) 4:Language[12-NNP]
                    (conj_and) 4:school[17-NN]
                         (det) 5:the[15-DT]
                         (nn) 5:language[16-NN]
                         (prep_of) 5:Institute[23-NNP]
                              (poss) 6:Washington[19-NNP]
                              (nn) 6:Foreign[21-NNP]
                              (nn) 6:Service[22-NNP]
```